# EVP_CIPHER* to name

Tags: openssl, libcrypto, evp-cipher

I've got an `EVP_CIPHER*` by using `EVP_get_cipherbyname("AES-256-CTR")`, now I would like to find a way to get from the `EVP_CIPHER*` back to the original name, in this case "AES-256-CTR".

Is there a method to do this in libcrypto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please look at EVP_CIPHER_name [here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/include/openssl/evp.h). See, if it can solve your purpose.

Comment: I do believe that may solve my problem. I'm so happy that it is documented ;-)

Comment: Why does the [google search on openssl.org](https://www.google.com/search?sitesearch=www.openssl.org&q=EVP_CIPHER_name) return no results for `EVP_CIPHER_name`?